# Are these called the "theories" of a set of formulas?

Tags: logic, computer-science, model-theory

In a logical system (which may or might not be the first order logic system), given a set $\Phi$ of formulas (or sentences),

- is there a name for $\{\text{formula }\phi\text{ | }\Phi \models \phi \}$?
- is there a name for $\{\text{formula }\phi\text{ | }\Phi \vdash \phi \}$?

Are they both called the "theories" of $\Phi$?

Is $\Phi$ called a set of axioms of the two?

Some thoughts and observations:

- The set of formulas satisfied by a structure is called the theory of the structure. (somewhere in Ebbinghaus' logic book.)
- On p111 In Enderton's logic book, if $Φ⊢$, then $$ is called a theorem of $Φ$.
- On p128 in Enderton's book, "Such a book would ﬁrst state the **logical axioms**
  and the rules of inference and would explain that they are acceptable to
  reasonable people. Then it would proceed to show that many formulas
  were deducible (or deducible from certain **nonlogical axioms**, such as
  axioms for set theory)."
- Is it correct that a theory is a set of theorems, and a theorem is a member of some theory or theories?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To make this question most significant, we want to work with a notion of "logical system" more-or-less along the following lines: a tuple $(Sent, \models, \vdash)$ where $\models$ is a relation between structures and sentences, $\vdash$ is a relation between sets of sentences and sentences, and $\models$ and $\vdash$ need not be connected by a completeness theorem (that is, it need not be the case that $\Gamma\vdash\varphi$ iff for every $\mathcal{M}$ with $\mathcal{M}\models\gamma$ for each $\gamma\in\Gamma$ we have $\mathcal{M}\models\varphi$).

The relevant term is "**deductive closure**." When $\models$ and $\vdash$ coincide (e.g. with first-order logic) there's nothing more to say. However, when $\models$ and $\vdash$ don't coincide - or are not known to coincide at this stage in the argument - this terminology has to be elaborated on. I don't think there's a standard terminology here, but here are the usages I've heard:

- "Deductive closure" for the $\vdash$-version and "entailment closure" for the $\models$-version.
- "Semantic deductive closure" and "syntactic deductive closure" for the $\models$-version and $\vdash$-version, respectively.

---

Re: your suggested terminology, "theory" is often used to refer to any set of sentences (or even formulas sometimes), so it would of course be inappropriate for this. When we add a closure condition, we can indeed talk about $T$ being *generated by* $\Gamma$ and we can talk about $\Gamma$ *axiomatizing* $T$. (We can do the latter using the looser meaning of "theory" too: we can say that $T_0$ axiomatizes $T_1$ iff they have the same deductive closures.)

However, we still have to distinguish between $\vdash$ and $\models$: does "theory" mean "$\vdash$-closed" or "$\models$-closed?"

Since the vast majority of logic takes place in the first-order context where we do have a completeness theorem, and more generally in logics whose $\models$ and $\vdash$ coincide, this point is largely ignorable; when it's important, my experience is that there is no really standard terminology and texts have to specify what language they're using.

Comment: Thanks. "'theory' is often used to refer to any set of sentences (or even formulas sometimes)". The theory of a set of structures is all the sentences satisfied by it, not any set of sentences. That is the only scenario, where I saw "theory" is used. But I haven't read many.

Comment: @Tim That's true - but (under this usage) not every theory is the theory of some class of structures, and that's not a problem. One point where it's important to use the looser notion is when computability theory is part of the picture: adopting the looser meaning, a computable theory will not in general have a computable deductive closure (think about Godel's incompleteness theorem: theories like $\mathsf{PA}$ or $\mathsf{ZFC}$ don't have computable deductive closures, even though they themselves are computable).

Comment: What sources does the definition of a theory you mentioned come from? You seem to define a theory as any set of sentences, not relative to a set of structures or a set of sentences.

Comment: @Tim "You seem to define a theory as any set of sentences, not relative to a set of structures or a set of sentences." That's right. For example, Chang/Keisler (one of the "big-name" books), page $12$: "A set $\Gamma$ of sentences is called a *theory*. A theory is said to be *closed* iff every consequence of $\Gamma$ belongs to $\Gamma$. A set $\Delta$ of sentences is said to be a *set of axioms for* a theory $\Gamma$ iff $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ have the same consequences." Here C/K use "consequence" in the $\models$-sense (bottom of page $11$). Note that this is introduced *after* completeness.

Comment: @Tim I actually forgot to mention another point of possible difference: do we demand that theories be *satisfiable*? C/K don't demand either satisfiability or closure; Ebbinghaus/Flum/Thomas demand both closure and satisfiability; and if I recall correctly, Marker requires closure but not satisfiability. Again, this is part of the general terminological phenomenon plaguing logic; it's best to pick a single approach (e.g. EFT) and stick with it entirely until mastered.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a demand. :)  Is an element in the theory of a structure called a theorem of the structure? I seems to have the impression that a theory is a set of theorems, wrong? On p111 In Enderton's logic book, if $\Phi \vdash \phi$, then $\phi$ is called a theorem of $\Phi$.  So in my original post, I thought that the set of theorems of $\Phi$ is similarly called the theory of $\Phi$?